# How to add following classes to the elements 'li', using method 'map'

Tags: jquery

Using method 'map' add following classes to the elements 'li' of each list 'ul': 1-st - 'sel', 2-nd - 'sel2',   3-rd - 'sel3', 4-th - 'sel'...

```
$("li").map(function() {

      var replacement = $( "<li>" ). $( this ).get( 0 );
      if ( index === 0,4 ) {
          $( replacement ).addClass("sel");
      }
      if ( index === 1,4 ) {
          $( replacement ).addClass("sel1");
      }
      if ( index === 2,5 ) {
          $( replacement ).addClass("sel2");
      }
      return replacement;
  });
```

Comment: what do you mean by `index === 0,4` ?

Comment: I would choose the first and the fourth element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `each` instead of `map`, because `map` is completly wrong for this task. And you can shorten your code a bit. ;)

```js
$("li").each(function(i) {
    var replacement = $(this),
        index = i > 0 && i < 3 ? ++i : '';

    replacement.addClass("sel" + index);
});
```

```css
.sel  { color: red; }
.sel2 { color: green; }
.sel3 { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Or with `map`, beacuse wished:

```js
$("li").map(function(i) {
    var replacement = $(this),
        index = i > 0 && i < 3 ? ++i : '';

    replacement.addClass("sel" + index);
});
```

```css
.sel  { color: red; }
.sel2 { color: green; }
.sel3 { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: needs to be done using the method "map" , it is important!

Comment: But that is completly wrong usage of `map`? Did you know what `map` is for? But okay. Made an example with `map` too. It is the same as with `each`. Just switch `each` with `map`. @ultimatum

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Your answer helped me a lot ! ))